FormArray with nested FormGroups. How to access the nested form group controls?
I have a FormArray with 3 FormGroups and each form group has 2 controls. Im not sure how to access the controls within the form groups to set the form control name.
setting up the form
this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
---a couple controls---
properties: this.formBuilder.array({
  first: this.formBuilder.group({ 
   label: new UntypedFormControl(),
   value: new UntypedFormControl(),
  }),
  second: this.formBuilder.group({ 
   label: new UntypedFormControl(),
   value: new UntypedFormControl(),
  }),
  third: this.formBuilder.group({ 
   label: new UntypedFormControl(),
   value: new UntypedFormControl(),
  }),
})
})

getter for properties form array
get properties() {
  return this.form.controls.properties as FormArray;
}

im able to add and delete a row of properties.
html for the form. Am not sure how to access the label and value controls in each form group from the form array.
<div formArrayName="properties">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let propertiesForm of properties.controls; let i = index">
  <div [formGroupName]="i">
---then I have 3 sets of mat form fields each with and label and value---
  </div>
  </ng-container>
</div>


formBuilder.array accept parameter which is an array value, but you are providing an object. I don't think this is working. If you want to adapt your object with first, second properties, you should consider to use the FormGroup.

this.formBuilder.array() method only accepts a parameter which is an array. You can't provide an object to it.
Approach 1: With this.formBuilder.array([])

Modify your properties structure to an array.
You can work with a loop to add the number of FormGroup that you need in the properties FormArray. And you should consider to implement a function to generate the single property FormGroup. This aims to reduce the code redundancy.

ngOnInit() {
  // Form with Form Array
  this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
    //---a couple controls---
    properties: this.formBuilder.array([]),
  });

  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    this.properties.push(this.createPropertyFormGroup());
}

createPropertyFormGroup() {
  return this.formBuilder.group({
    label: new UntypedFormControl(),
    value: new UntypedFormControl(),
  });
}

<form [formGroup]="form">
  <div formArrayName="properties">
    <ng-container
      *ngFor="let propertiesForm of properties.controls; let i = index"
    >
      <div [formGroupName]="i">
        <label>Label: </label>
        <input formControlName="label" />
        <br />

        <label>Value: </label>
        <input formControlName="value" />
      </div>
      <hr />
    </ng-container>
  </div>
</form>


Approach 2: With this.formBuilder.group({})

In HTML, you need the KeyValuePipe to iterate the properties FormGroup object and generate each FormGroup.

this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
  //---a couple controls---
  properties: this.formBuilder.group({
    first: this.createPropertyFormGroup(),
    second: this.createPropertyFormGroup(),
    third: this.createPropertyFormGroup(),
  }),
});

get propertiesFormGroup() {
  return this.form.controls['properties'] as FormGroup;
}

<form [formGroup]="form">
  <div formGroupName="properties">
    <ng-container
      *ngFor="let propertiesForm of propertiesFormGroup.controls | keyvalue;"
    >
      <div [formGroupName]="propertiesForm.key">
        <label>Label: </label>
        <input formControlName="label" />
        <br />

        <label>Value: </label>
        <input formControlName="value" />
      </div>
      <hr />
    </ng-container>
  </div>
</form>

Demo @ StackBlitz
